# JAVA 8 : RowMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I use RowMapper to map the database tables to java objects

my request looks like the one below

```
SELECT  SUM(quantity) FROM table1 t1 
WHERE    t1.x = 723834 AND      t1.y = 0  
UNION ALL
  SELECT  SUM(quantity2) FROM table t2 
  WHERE    t2.x = 723834 AND      t2.y > 0  
  UNION ALL
   SELECT  nombre FROM table3 
   WHERE  rownum=1
```

When I look at the result of the query on the GUI is like that :

```
SUM(quantity)
20    
4
30
```

and the implementation of my RowMapper is like :

```
    public Transit mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Double ql=rs.getDouble(1);
        rs.next();
        Double qe=rs.getDouble(1);
        rs.next();
        return Transit.builder().qteLivree(ql).qteExpediee(qe)
            .nombreJoursOuvrables(rs.getInt(1))
            .build();
}
```

Also I would like to know is there any other method to be able to retrieve without using rs.next() by what I do not receive the good values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a ResultSetExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-).

A RowMapper, as its name indicates, is supposed to map **one** row of the ResultSet, and Spring is in charge of alling it for each returned row. Since you want to transform several rows of the result set in a single Transit object, you should use a `ResultSetExtractor`.